# Athena: querying GeoJSON

Tags: geojson, well-known-text

Let's say I have a dataset with one column being GeoJSONs encoded as string.

AWS Athena supports ESRI and hence geo queries on geometries: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/geospatial-functions-list.html

However, this works only for WKT/WKB objects.

Is there a way to import and query GeoJSONs in AWS Athena?
Or does one have to convert GeoJSONs into WKT/WKB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AWS says it's possible if you use ESRI-compliant GeoJSONs (what that means exactly I'm not sure, but it seems that [this would be an example](https://github.com/Esri/gis-tools-for-hadoop/tree/master/samples/data/counties-data)).

This is the DDL for creating the table (though I wasn't able to make it work with my QGIS-generated GeoJSONs):

```
CREATE external TABLE IF NOT EXISTS counties
 (
 Name string,
 BoundaryShape binary
 )
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.esri.hadoop.hive.serde.JsonSerde'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'com.esri.json.hadoop.EnclosedJsonInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION 's3://my-query-log/json/';
```

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/geospatial-example-queries.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess the AWS doc has been updated to show the example of ESRI-compliant GeoJSON file for counties.

Also to highlight, that    `'com.esri.json.hadoop.EnclosedJsonInputFormat'` serializer will be used to convert the GeoJSON format to GeoSpatial Binary format, known to PostGIS Spatial (ST_) functions here: https://postgis.net/docs/reference.html

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/geospatial-example-queries.html